# LogParser Case-Sensitive Search

Tags: case-sensitive, logparser

I'm trying to match a specific URI in an IIS log using LogParser. There are multiple requests coming in for the same address but with slightly different cases. How can I pull up a single URI by case?

For instance: "myPath\ThIsPaGe.aspx" vs "mypath\thispage.aspx"

Comment: Are you trying to exactly match one, but not the other?  Or are you trying to match both?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE` instead of `=`

```
select *
from 'logfilename'
where cs-uri-stem LIKE 'myPath\ThIsPaGe.aspx'
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Comment: Given that LogParser's only function is to execute SQL-like queries, what part of it would you like to see clarified?

Comment: Would someone new to LogParser understand the difference between using `LIKE` and `=`, and would they be enlightened by reading your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use ToLower or ToUpper case on your paths. This is from String object.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `To_Lowercase` as follows:

```
SELECT To_Lowercase(cs-uri-stem) as Res, cs-method, cs-status
WHERE Res = 'mypath\thispage.aspx'
...
```

The advantage of this is that it can simplify group by reporting.